# Metro bundler is not starting for ios project

Tags: ios, react-native, ios-simulator, metro-bundler

Metro bundler is not opening for my react native ios app. I have run the android app of the same project in my smart phone(not in android emulator) and it has no problem. Everything  went well - starting metro bundler automatically and bundling successfully. The issue is only with the ios app. The ios app was working fine before today.Yesterday I uploaded ios app in testflight by changing version code and build in xcode.Is the issue because of any problem with simulator or xcode. I have tried some solutions from github and stackoverflow but no change yet.

Tested with other ios react native projects and they too have the same problem.

While running using npx react-native run-ios command the ios simulator is starting without opening metro bundler and after nothing happens. The terminal just showing Building app.....   Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by waiting more than 45 minutes. It takes time to build and starting the metro bundler. So If anyone come across with this issue, just wait to start the bundler.